# How to Add annotations for array of characters?

Tags: frama-c

I am a newbie with Frama-C and I've been looking for some annotations regarding how you write annotations for char array. Usually in the examples I see they are using integers. So I am not really sure if what I wrote is correct.

I have this function:

```
    User *login(char id[25], char pass[25], User *list);
```

I wrote the annotations like the one below but I am not really sure:

```
    /*@ requires \valid(list);
      @ requires \valid_range(id, 0, 25-1);
      @ requires \valid_range(pass, 0, 25-1);
    */
```

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to tell for sure without having an informal description of what your function is supposed to take as argument, but your specification seems indeed correct, although it might be slightly incomplete. Here is what your `requires` says about the arguments:

- `list` must be a valid pointer
- `id` and `pass` must be pointers (remember that in *formals* declarations, you don't have arrays, only pointers) to blocks of (at least) 25 `char`. More precisely, you must be able to dereference `id`, `id+1` ... `id+24`.

Note that `\valid_range` is deprecated in favor of `\valid(id+(0 .. 24-1))` which carries exactly the same meaning.

These requirements make sense, but, depending on what the function is supposed to do, you might need other ones. For instance, are `id` and `pass` supposed to be 0-terminated string?